# change the number every second but also make the number go down once button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a clicker game, so when you buy things, it brings your points down while also making the points go up every second. My problem is that when you buy the upgrade, it brings it down by 15 points, but when the auto thing brings my points up by only one, it goes back to 15 or higher. Here is my code so far:

```js
var i = 0;
num = document.getElementById('number');

function Add() {
  i++;
  num.innerText = i;
}

function AutoThing() {
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = i - 15;
  setInterval(increase, 1000)
}

function increase() {
  if (i > 0) {
    i++;
    num.innerText = i;
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <p id="number">0</p>
  <br>
  <button onclick="Add()">Add 1</button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="AutoThing()">auto clicker 15$</button>
</center>
```

Comment: Your `AutoThing` never changes `i` itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple situations:

- The setInterval runs forever. If you call it multiple times, will run multiple times forever;
- the function AutoThing was not changing the i;
- use lowerCamelCase on function names (works with any case, but it's not recommended);
- The i is initialized with 0, and the "increase" method does nothing when i === 0. Maybe it's a bug, or it's a feature;

```js
var i = 0;
num = document.getElementById('number');

function add() {
    i++;
    num.innerText = i;
}

function autoThing() {
    if (i <= 15) {
        return;
    }
    i-=15;
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = i;
    
}

function increase() {
    if (i > 0) {
        i++;
        num.innerText = i;
    }
}

setInterval(increase, 1000)
```

```html
<!dotype html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
  <p id="number">
  0
  </p>
  <br>
  <button onclick="add()">
  Add 1
  </button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="autoThing()">
  auto clicker 15$
  </button>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify what you have by making `add` take a number to add to `i`.

```
var i = 0;

function add(amount) {
    i += amount;
    document.getElementById('number').innerText = i;
}

function autoThing() {
    add(-15);
}

setInterval(() => add(1), 1000)
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
  <p id="number">
  0
  </p>
  <br>
  <button onclick="add(1)">
  Add 1
  </button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="autoThing()">
  auto clicker 15$
  </button>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```